# Center window of a Pygame Zero game

Tags: python, pgzero

I am using the easy-to-use Python library `pgzero` for programming games.

How can I center the game window? )It always opens at a random position...

```
import pgzrun

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

pgzrun.go()
```

Note: I am using the runtime helper lib `pgzrun` to make the game executable without an OS shell command... It implicitly imports the `pgzero` lib...

**Edit:** `pgzero` uses `pygame` internally, perhaps there is a way to center the window using the `pygame` API...

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope It will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

This line of code tries to center your window the best it can.

**Try this:**

```
import pgzrun
import os

TITLE = "Hello World"

WIDTH  = 800
HEIGHT = 600

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: I have a problem using this command with my students that just download the latest version of pygames. `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'` Works for me I think because I running 1.9.6, but it doesn't work for any of my students that are running pygames 2.0.1. Is there a different syntax for this with the latest version of pygames?